# Perimeter of triangle inside

Tags: conic-sections

Given an ellipse centered at $(3,-3)$, and has a focus at $(3,-8)$.

What is the perimeter of a triangle that entirely lies within the ellipse and has two of its vertices on the foci of the ellipse and the other vertex lies on any point on the circumference of the ellipse?

Answer (score 1):

The perimeter is the sum of the length of the principle axis of the ellipse and the distance between the foci. This is a definition of an ellipse. See this [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html) for details.

Comment: nice point. But, how to find the length of the major axis here?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't think there is sufficient information provided in the question to find the length of the major axis. All we know is $ae = 5$ ($2a$ is the principle axis). That is why I answered in terms of definitions, and not distances.